# Use session state to redirect user to homepage if already logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a login page and and a accounts controller with Login action. When I log in I get redirected to home page(which is good) but after logging in if I re visit the login page it shows the login form again (although I am logged in).
I tried check for session state values but every time I try to use it I get null reference error.

```
public ActionResult Login(string name, string password, string hash)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            var user = _model.tblUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.username == name);
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.powerLevel == 0)
                {
                    Session["IsAdmin"] = (user.password == password);
                    Session["IsAuthor"] = null;
                    Session["IsUser"] = null;
                }
                else if (user.powerLevel == 1)
                {
                    Session["IsAdmin"] = null;
                    Session["IsAuthor"] = (user.password == password);
                    Session["IsUser"] = null;
                }
                else if (user.powerLevel == 2)
                {

                    Session["IsAdmin"] = null;
                    Session["IsAuthor"] = null;
                    Session["IsUser"] = (user.password == password);
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("Login");
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Posts");
            }
        }
        return View("Login");
    }
```

so if either of IsAdmin, IsAuthor, IsUser Session is set to true I want to get redirected to homepage. I tried check it with string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace but it doesnt work I always get false even if the Session is set to true

Comment: Please don't put plain text (or even hashed) passwords in your URL. That's extremely insecure.

Comment: @gunr2171 dont worry. After I figure this out I will convert the password to sha256 using jquey and then send it to Action

Comment: Is this the post action of the controller?  It seem you dont show us proper part of your code.  What is the controller default action (index)?

Comment: @DanielBlais yes this post action controller. I currently dont have anything index only working on /Login and /Logout

Comment: This is the post action of an form.  You want to catch if the user is already logged (by checking the session).  You have to check in the GET action that display that view/form, not in the POST action.